# How would I force update div content-editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing something with javascript on `Youtube chat` and when I use javascript to change the chatbox, and there's a counter on the bottom right which shows how many characters my message is, it won't update before I hit any button to refresh it.

At the moment I'm using this:

```
$('#input #input')[0].innerHTML = newMessage;
```

to change the text, and if you hit enter right after the text has been changed the sent message is not there. I believe there's some kind of on change event that it checks what's in the chatbox. I tried triggering `onchange` event multiple different ways but couldn't make it. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Use the JQuery `keypress()` method like this:

```
    <input id="target" type="text">

<script>

   $( "#target" ).keypress(function( event ) {
     // your logic here...
     console.log('code character ' + event.which);

   });
</script>
```

or also you can use `keydown`, `keyup` methods

more information [keypress](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)